# IndexTank: why does InstantSearch ask me for a username and password?

Tags: indextank

I downloaded the tarball from the [IndexTank JQuery Github](https://github.com/flaptor/indextank-jquery) page and extracted the archive as the instructions told me to.

I edited the test.html file and added my IndexTank public API URL and also my index name as per the instructions.

Then I opened the test.html file in Chrome and tried to use the search field.

So, my question is this:

*Why, everytime I search for something, am I prompted with a browser popup asking me to enter in my username and password?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to go to your dashboard, click on Manage for your index and enable Public Search API. The option is right below the scoring functions.